# UK visa procedure

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, vfs-global

I am Indian resident and applying for UK visitor visa from India.

Previously, I had applied for the same type of visa at same place. During last time, I submitted all my original/copies of required documents at VFS global.

However, this time it is asking to upload documents. My question is whether the procedure has changed and do we need to upload all documents rather than submitting at VFS?

Kindly guide me for the process.

Comment: Does the VFS website state that submitting paper documents is an option?

Answer (score 3):

Now there is an option to scan and upload all the supporting documents on the VFS Global website for each applicant for UK Visa. If all documents are uploaded properly, then you can visit the VFS center for your bio-metric appointment with only your current valid and old passports.

You can also choose to take all your original documents and VFS will scan and upload these for you for a fee (Rs 750). AFAIK this service is currently being offered for free (limited time) and you can opt for the same on the VFS website while managing your application. This  should let you know the charges for the same if there is any. I finished my submission on April 8th at Bangalore and it was free then.

I faced issues while uploading documents (relating to the size and number of documents allowed for each category) so please try it out with time to spare and make your decision. Note that once you opt for the document scan & upload service at VFS centre, you will no longer have the option to upload the documents yourself.

My advice would be to carry all the original documents to your appointment even if you managed to upload all of them OK on the VFS website, just to be on the safer side.

Comment: Very good answer!